# Using pgtol in R's optim function

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to use `pgtol` in R's optim function and not getting anywhere.

I optimize [this function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function)

```
RosenbrockFactory <- function(a,b) {
  function(v) {
    return( (a-v[1])^2 + b*(v[2]-v[1]^2)^2 )
  } 
}
# the exact function to optimize
fn <- RosenbrockFactory(2,3)
```

I use this helper function to get the gradient at a=2, b=3

```
gradR <- function(v) {
  x <- v[1]
  y <- v[2]
  gr <- rep(0,2)
  gr[1] <- -2 * (2-x) - 12 * (y-x^2)*x
  gr[2] <- 3*2*(y-x^2)
  return(gr)
}
```

default optimization, and check, gradient higher than I want

```
fn <- RosenbrockFactory(2,3)
opt0 <- optim(c(0,0), fn, method="L-BFGS-B")
gradR(opt0$par)
# [1]  9.060194e-05 -3.449572e-05
```

The R `stats` package help for `optim` documentation says, "helps control the convergence of the "L-BFGS-B" method. It is a tolerance on the projected gradient in the current search direction. This defaults to zero, when the check is suppressed."

This only says what happens with pgtol is 0, doesn't say what non-zero values do, so try a large value of 1e10:

```
opt10 <- optim(c(0,0), fn, method="L-BFGS-B", control=list(pgtol=1e10))
gradR(opt10$par)
# [1] -4  0
opt10$par
# [1] 0 0
```

that stops any optimization. Okay, try going the other way:

```
optm10 <- optim(c(0,0), fn, method="L-BFGS-B", control=list(pgtol=1e-10))
gradR(optm10$par)
# [1]  9.060194e-05 -3.449572e-05
```

The small value (`1e-10`) changed nothing relative to before I changed `pgtol`. So, I try cranking that up

```
optm300 <- optim(c(0,0), fn, method="L-BFGS-B", control=list(pgtol=1e-300))
gradR(optm300$par)
# [1]  9.060194e-05 -3.449572e-05
```

so, it did nothing again for about the smallest double.

Just verify, I can optimize this with Newton's method

```
Newton <- function(x0, tol) {
  xi <- x0
  grNorm <- tol*2 # let iteration start
  while( grNorm > tol) {
    f0 <- fn(xi)
    gr <- gradR(xi)
    H <- hessR(xi)
    step <- -1 * qr.solve(qr(H), gr)
    xi <- xi + step
    grNorm <- sqrt(sum(gr*gr))
  }
  return(xi)
}

hessR <- function(v) {
  x <- v[1]
  y <- v[2]
  H <- matrix(0, nrow=2, ncol=2)
  H[1,1] <- 2 - 12 * y + 36*x^2
  H[1,2] <- H[2,1] <- -12*x
  H[2,2] <-  6
  return(H)
}


n1 <- Newton(c(-1,2), 1e-1)
gradR(n1)
# [1]  0.0010399242 -0.0002601235
n2 <- Newton(c(-1,2), 1e-2)
gradR(n2)
# [1] -1.461804e-10 -4.822809e-13
n3 <- Newton(c(-1,2), 1e-3)
gradR(n3)
# [1] 0 0
print(n3 - c(2,4), digits=16) # exactly at the correct answer
```

so here the lower I set the tolerance the closer I get. Of course, once Newton's method is close it gets the exact answer.

This is a MWE to show that I cannot get L-BFGS-G to continue until the gradient is as small as I ask for a function that is somewhat difficult to optimize but Newton's method can, in fact, solve it exactly.

Any idea how `pgtol` works or what I can do to convince `optim` to keep going until the optimization has found a result below a prespecified gradient size? I'd accept this in norm, I just want to be able to encourage it to keep going.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that with method "L-BFGS-B" the option to control the convergence is 'factr'!

```
opt0 <- optim(c(0,0), fn, method="L-BFGS-B",
              control = list(factr = 1e-10))

opt0$par            #>  1.999988  3.999952
gradR(opt0$par)     #> -2.399986e-05  0.000000e+00
```

Methods like "L-BFGS-B" minimize the function values, they do *not* attempt to make the gradient as small as possible at the optimal point.

There are more modern optimization functions for R, see the "Optimization and Mathematical Programming" Task View.

```
library(lbfgsb3c)

lbfgsb3(c(0,0), fn, control = list(factr = 1e-10))
$par
[1] 2 4
$grad
[1]  5.846166e-14 -3.804366e-14
```

This uses the Fortran implementation of "L-BFGS-B" by Nocedal et al.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, factr controls the L-BFGS-B method, but the current pgtol manual entry text is, "helps control the convergence of the 'L-BFGS-B' method. It is a tolerance on the projected gradient in the current search direction. This defaults to zero, when the check is suppressed." And that's what I want to use as a convergence criterion: a function of the gradient. I'll look at lbfgsb3c, thanks for that tip.

Comment: I think you are misled by a - maybe unclear - help entry. The solver stops when the minimum is reached with sufficient accuracy, even if the projected gradient is larger than pgtol. You will only change this behavior by interfering with the code.

Comment: in what sense does `pgtol` "help control the convergence"?

Comment: You saw this with your `1e10` test: It stops the iteration if the projected gradient is smaller than `pgtol`; but it does *not* force the iteration to continue *until* the gradient is smaller. Very small gradients can be a computation/precision problem for BFGS methods, and `pgtol` helps to avoid it. --
I admit this is an "educational guess". If you want to know better, post on Stackoverflow with tag  "[mathematical-optimization]" (no "[r]"), as your question is largely independent of any implementation.